# java bean representation read prefix:attrName

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to read an attribute of xml by JAXB and java beans:
This is the full xml:

```
    <dad xml:lang="en">
    </dad>
```

I need to get the lang attribute:
my java bean representation is as follows:
This is the java representation of the xml:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "dad")
    public class dad {
    @XmlAttribute(namespace = "xml", required=true, name = "lang")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String xmlLang;
    public String getXmlLang() {
    return xmlLang;
    }

    public void setXmlLang(String value) {
    this.xmlLang = value;
    }
    }
```

This is the code which i use while unmarshalling:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("dad.model");
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    dad doc = (dad) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(dad),"UTF-8"));
    System.err.println(doc.getXmlLang());
```

But it gives me null?!
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Show us the full XML, the full class and the code that unmarshalls it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace isn't `xml`. `xml` is just the identifier. The actual, reserved, namespace is `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. So your annotation should be

```
@XmlAttribute(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", required = true, name = "lang")
```

Comment: @MohammedQwaider You're welcome. Note that the `xml` name and namespace are reserved, but you can declare pretty much any other.